# Spawning multiple Action Clients from one node

Tags: ros, simpleactionclient, threads

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I am creating several action server nodes to cater to different kinds of Actions that I need to perform. However, I find it inefficient to create 'n' Action Clients for the 'n' # of Action Servers that I have. Though I still want to be able to timeout the Action after a duration x. The only way I see to do this is to sendGoal and wait for x seconds. The wait() will block my node though, preventing other goals to get sent. If I dont wait() I can send multiple goals to multiple servers, however will not be able to timeout of the Action after x seconds. Could someone suggest to me good ways to sendGoal and timeout, without blocking? Perhaps Threads?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50949/spawning-multiple-action-clients-from-one-node/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found exactly what I needed!

http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Callback%20Based%20Simple%20Action%20Client

---

Originally posted by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) with karma: 289 on 2012-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0